# enforcing Faraday adapter :typhoeus to use HTTP/2 for requests

Tags: ruby, http2, faraday, typhoeus

How to enforce `Faraday` adapter [typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus/blob/master/lib/typhoeus/adapters/faraday.rb) to use HTTP/2 for requests to servers which supported HTTP/2?
I have tested this over service https://http2.pro/doc/api and result was like this:

```
body="{\"http2\":1,\"protocol\":\"HTTP\\/2.0\",\"push\":0,\"user_agent\":\"Faraday v0.12.2\"}",
```

`\"http2\":1,` what means that HTTP/2 not used for request!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two things at play here. The first is that the remote API is lying to you in the response body. Their documentation says:

> http2: Possible values are 0 (HTTP/2 was used) and 1 (HTTP/2 was not used).

Even though the response body shows `'http2': 1` indicating that HTTP2 was not used, it **is** being used. You can most easily confirm this using Chrome's dev tools:

[image: HTTP2 was used]

So once we know that the API is lying in the response body, how can we independently confirm that Typhoeus is using HTTP2?

(this answer assumes you are using `pry` as your REPL, not IRB)

First let's confirm that Typhoeus alone will use HTTP2:

```
require 'typhoeus'
response = Typhoeus.get("https://http2.pro/api/v1", http_version: :httpv2_0)
response.class
=> Typhoeus::Response < Object
response.body
=> "{\"http2\":1,\"protocol\":\"HTTP\\/2.0\",\"push\":0,\"user_agent\":\"Typhoeus - https:\\/\\/github.com\\/typhoeus\\/typhoeus\"}" # this is the lying API response
response.http_version
=> "2" # this is what Typhoeus tells us was actually used
```

Now let's test it in Faraday:

```
require 'faraday'
require 'typhoeus'
require 'typhoeus/adapters/faraday'

conn = Faraday.new do |faraday|
  faraday.adapter :typhoeus, http_version: :httpv2_0
end

response = conn.get("https://http2.pro/api/v1")
response.body
=> "{\"http2\":1,\"protocol\":\"HTTP\\/2.0\",\"push\":0,\"user_agent\":\"Faraday v0.17.0\"}" # again we get the lying API response
```

But how can we confirm it was HTTP2? This doesn't work:

```
response.http_version
NoMethodError: undefined method `http_version' for #<Faraday::Response:0x00007f99935519a8>
```

Because `response` isn't a `Typhoeus::Response` object, it's a Faraday object:

```
response.class
=> Faraday::Response < Object
```

So we need to get into the gem itself to figure out where it's creating the `Typhoeus::Response` object so we can call `.http_version` on it manually and confirm it's using the protocol we expect. As it turns out, that's [right here](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus/blob/cbab8c9f39167e1ae78ed65e5baeb1dbb53cfbdc/lib/typhoeus/adapters/faraday.rb#L127).

Let's take the easy route and stick `binding.pry` into our local copy of the gem (you'll need to restart pry to pick up the changes to the gem):

```
  def typhoeus_request(env)
    opts = {
      :method => env[:method],
      :body => env[:body],
      :headers => env[:request_headers]
    }.merge(@adapter_options)
    binding.pry
    ::Typhoeus::Request.new(env[:url].to_s, opts)
  end
```

Then re-run the request:

```
require 'faraday'
require 'typhoeus'
require 'typhoeus/adapters/faraday'

conn = Faraday.new do |faraday|
  faraday.adapter :typhoeus, http_version: :httpv2_0
end

response = conn.get("https://http2.pro/api/v1")
```

And you'll see:

```
Frame number: 0/3

From: /Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/typhoeus-1.3.1/lib/typhoeus/adapters/faraday.rb @ line 127 Faraday::Adapter::Typhoeus#typhoeus_request:

    120: def typhoeus_request(env)
    121:   opts = {
    122:     :method => env[:method],
    123:     :body => env[:body],
    124:     :headers => env[:request_headers]
    125:   }.merge(@adapter_options)
    126:   binding.pry
 => 127:   ::Typhoeus::Request.new(env[:url].to_s, opts)
    128: end
```

Now enter:

```
response = ::Typhoeus::Request.new(env[:url].to_s, opts).run
```

And confirm it's a `Typhoeus::Response` object:

```
response.class
=> Typhoeus::Response < Object
```

And confirm it's using HTTP2:

```
response.http_version
=> "2"
```

And confirm the API response body is a dirty liar:

```
response.body
=> "{\"http2\":1,\"protocol\":\"HTTP\\/2.0\",\"push\":0,\"user_agent\":\"Faraday v0.17.0\"}"
```

And that's how you use Typhoeus as a Faraday adapter to make an HTTP2 request.

Comment: "remote API is lying"... the API is clearly not lying. The documentation just has an obvious typo. Clearly the response is a "boolean" 1=true or 0=false indicating wether or not http2 was used. To put it mildly, it would be insanse if the api returned `http2=0` to indicate `http2` was used.

But anyways, very nice explanation on how to debug this sort of thing with Ruby +1